# Stack overflow error due to long lineage in loop for (on DataFrame)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an iterative algorithm (pyspark) in which I make update on a part of my Spark DataFrame. I do it via a loop for and at each iteration, my job becomes more expensive and have more long lineage. At iteration i, I have lineage of iteration `i-1 +` some steps (lineage becomes more and more long).
I tried many options to break lineage but it doesn't work. Here is my source code. I work on jupyterLab VM.

```
def chronologically_compute(myDataFrame, number_of_compute, spark_session):
    # UDFs
    find_law_to_apply_udf = udf(find_law_to_apply, IntegerType())
    compute_loss_udf = udf(compute_loss, FloatType())

    TIMING = []

    #myDataFrame = myDataFrame.repartition(1000)
    spark_session.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("myDirectory")
    #myDataFrame.explain(True)
    #myDataFrame.checkpoint()

    for i in range(1, number_of_compute + 1):
        
        debutRank = time.time()
        print("Itération", i)
        myDataFrame = myDataFrame.withColumn("column1", 
                                             when(myDataFrame.rank == i, find_law_to_apply_udf("updatedComputed")
                                                 ).otherwise(myDataFrame.column1))
        myDataFrame = myDataFrame.withColumn("SelectedValue", 
                                             when(myDataFrame.rank == i, myDataFrame["column2"].getItem(col("column1") - 1)
                                                 ).otherwise(myDataFrame.SelectedValue))
        myDataFrame = myDataFrame.withColumn("computed", 
                                             when(myDataFrame.rank == i, compute_loss_udf("SelectedValue", "Time")
                                                 ).otherwise(myDataFrame.computed))
        window = Window.partitionBy('ID')
        myDataFrame = myDataFrame.withColumn('computedSum', sum("computed").over(window))
        myDataFrame = myDataFrame.withColumn('updatedComputed', 
                                             when(myDataFrame.rank == i, myDataFrame.computedSum + myDataFrame.updatedComputed
                                                 ).otherwise(myDataFrame.updatedComputed))
        myDataFrame = myDataFrame.withColumn('updatedComputed', 
                                             when(myDataFrame.rank == i + 1, myDataFrame.computedSum + myDataFrame.updatedComputed
                                                 ).otherwise(myDataFrame.updatedComputed))   
        if i % 10 == 0:
            d = time.time()
            myDataFrame.checkpoint()
            print(myDataFrame.count())
            #myDataFrame.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY_2) 
            duree_lineage = time.time() - d
            print("Lineage took {0}".format(duree_lineage))
            TIMING.append(duree_lineage)

        duree = time.time() - debutRank
        print("Modif took {0}".format(duree))
             
    print("Iteration time sum", np.sum(TIMING)) 
    print("Iteration time avg", np.mean(TIMING))

return myDataFrame




def main(spark_session):
    try:
        spark_jobs(spark_session)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        raise 
        

if __name__ == "__main__":

SPARK_SESSION = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("AppName") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .config('spark.executor.memory','2g') \
    .config('spark.driver.memory','2g') \
    .config('spark.driver.maxResultsSize','2g') \
    .config("spark.logLineage", "true") \
    .config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions","-Xss32M") \
    .getOrCreate()

main(SPARK_SESSION)

SPARK_SESSION.stop()
```

Comment: You could try the following: write a job that executes one iteration and which persists its result. Then call the same job again working on the output of the first and so on. If this works successfully, you could try to do all iterations in a single job. But potentially the lineage is not the only performance problem.

Comment: I finaly serialize data as csv file and reload it at each step. this breaks the lineage and resolve the problem.